# changing font family based on locale

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, sass

This is what i have.

html head:

```
<head lang="<%= I18n.locale %>">
```

scss:

```
body {
  html[lang="en"] & {
    font: normal 13px/140% "Helvetica Neue", verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  html[lang="ja"] & {
    font: normal 13px/140% "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック" , MS PGothic, "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro, Osaka, sans-serif;
  }
}
```

but the scss doesnt seem to work, it does not change the font family when changing locales

Comment: This is not a valid CSS. Are you using a CSS Pre-processor?

Comment: i'm using sass/scss. sorry forgot to specify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `lang` attribute on the `html` element, not the `head` element, if you use selectors like `html[lang="en"]`.

Comment: +1 Nice catch! Am not sure about the output of `<%= I18n.locale %>` however the OP may need to use `[attr|=value]` selector also.