# How to initialize vutify3 $body-font-family with different font families based on nuxtI18n locale language in a multilingual app?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt-i18n

I am developing a multilingual app that should support both Farsi and English languages with Nuxt3 and Vurtify3. I've searched through different websites but I didn't find any solution in order to assign differnt font families to $body-font-family based on selected language?
How can I change app's font family when the app's language changed?

Comment: Give a try to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305712) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25619949/8816585). Otherwise, something JS-based could also work but probably less performant overall. Not really a nuxt thing per se. Also, what are you using for your i18n + nuxt version/libraries exactly? Mind giving more details please?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, but I don't think that this can help my case. Nuxt i18n version is 8.0.0-beta.12 and Nuxt version is 3.6.1. I believe that using Pinia and the store can help. If I come to a solution I will share it. @kissu

Comment: Oh sorry, missed out on the Vuetify part indeed. Vuetify has its own variable injection flow I think. Still, maybe it works with regular CSS (or is it SCSS only)?